# "Reduction modulo $p$" of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $\chi$ is a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$. I sometimes see the notion of "reduction modulo $p$ of $\chi$" (which I will denote by $\chi_p$). 
What is meant here ? Is it just $\chi \otimes_{\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})} \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ ?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: What means $\chi \otimes_{\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})} \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ ? (when say $\chi = Spec(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x)$) @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @reuns $\text{Spec}(\Bbb F_p[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x))$.

Comment: I doubt that but in term of morphisms and ringed spaces I don't see

Comment: @reuns It can be seen in the category of commutative rings, in where fibered product of affine schemes is translated into tensor product of algebras.

Comment: @Phil.Z So you are saying I should look at $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ? Then $p u\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} a=u\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} a p =u\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} 0 = 0 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}0$ so that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x)$, and something similar should happen for the local rings

Comment: @reuns Yes. More generally, one has $B\otimes_A A/I\cong B/IB$ for any $A$-algebra $B$ and any ideal $I$ in $A$.

Comment: @Boccherini : you might accept the answer, if it is fine to you. Otherwise, you could tell me how I can improve it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. As in the definition in II.3, p. 88, from Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, if $X$ is a scheme (over $\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$) and $p \in \Bbb Z$ is a prime number, then the reduction mod $p$ of $X$ is
$$X_p := X \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z)} \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb F_p)$$

This is just the fiber of the structural morphism $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$ above $p\Bbb Z \in \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$.

---

As an example, if $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z[X_1, ..., X_n] / (f_1, ..., f_m))$ is of finite type over $\Bbb Z$, then 
$$X_p \cong 
\mathrm{Spec}\left(
\Bbb F_p[X_1, ..., X_n] / (\overline{f_1}, ..., \overline{f_m})
\right),$$
as a scheme over $\Bbb F_p$, where $\overline{f_j}$ denotes the reduction mod $p$ of $f_j \in \Bbb Z[X_1, ..., X_n]$.

Said differently, the reduction of an affine variety (over $\Bbb Z$) defined by the equation, say, $y^2-x^3+1=0$ (over $\Bbb Q$, it is an *elliptic curve*) gives you the variety $y^2 - x^3 + [1]_p=0$ over $\Bbb F_p$ (which is [*not*](https://algebrateahousejmath.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/reduction-types-of-elliptic-curves/) an elliptic curve if $p<5$).

Comment: When I say "it is an elliptic curve", I mean that the projectivization $y^2z - x^3 + z^3 = 0$ is an elliptic curve.